# Can I Put Extra Parameters in Backing Bean's Getters and Setters in JSF?

Tags: jsf

I'm playing around with genericizing some JSF pages.  One of the features that's been requested is making them fieldname-agnostic -- passing in fieldnames as parameters rather than having them bound to specific getters/setters in the backing bean.

So instead of binding a specific field like this:

```
<custom:editor value="#{backingViewBean.editorValue}" />
```

... to the back-end methods like these:

```
public String getEditorValue() ...
public void setEditorValue(String editorValue) ...
```

... I'm trying to bind it to back-end methods like these:

```
public String getFieldValue(String fieldName) ...
public void setFieldValue(String fieldName, String fieldValue) ...
```

Is there some elegant way I can do this with the `value` attribute mimicking how getters and setters usually behave?  Or does this approach require more complexity than that?

Comment: Don't know if that meets your needs, but have you seen the array notation: `#{backingViewBean[decidingBean.fieldName]}`?

Comment: @mabi:  Ooh.  That looks very promising.  I'll investigate that.

Answer (score 2):

For me it looks like you are searching for a ways to set one pair of getter and setter for all your variables inside your bean so if you are to 'lazy' them for alle your data in your managed bean you can implement `java.util.Map` into the bean then you can overwrite the put and get Methode like this:
public class DataBean implements Serializable, java.util.Map {

```
public class DataBean implements Serializable, java.util.Map {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private final HashMap<String, Object> BeanData;

    public DataBean(){
        BeanData = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    }

    @Override
    public Object get(final Object key) {
        if (key == null) {throw new IllegalArgumentException("Key cannot be null.");}
        return BeanData.get(key);
    }

    @Override
    public Object put(final Object key, final Object value) {
        if (key == null) {throw new IllegalArgumentException("Key cannot be null.");}
        BeanData.put(key.toString(), value);
        return null;
    }
```

This will allow you to store values in your bean without creating getter and setter for every var in your bean:

```
  <h:inputText  value="#{dataBean.key1}"></h:inputText>
  <h:outputLabel value="#{dataBean.key1}"></h:outputLabel>
  <h:inputText  value="#{dataBean.key2}"></h:inputText>
  <h:outputLabel value="#{dataBean.key2}"></h:outputLabel>
```